# Disposing SelectionListener In SWT on click of another button

Tags: java, swt

I have a code which adds four check box button to SWT shell , i have added selection Listener to the checkBox buttons , which i want to remove on click of OK,CANCEL and CLOSE button of SWT Shell , How can i dispose such event , this is my code

```
grpVersionTreeComponents.setLayoutData(componentsRenderer.createGridData(490, 220, 4));
            for(int versionCount = 0; versionCount < versionSplitters.length ; versionCount++ ){
                String splitter= versionSplitters[versionCount];
                Button cbVersionSplitter = new CheckBoxWrapper().getButton(grpVersionTreeComponents,splitter.toString() , "");
                cbVersionSplitter.setEnabled(true);
                versionSplitterCheckBoxList.add(cbVersionSplitter);
                versionSplitterCheckBoxList.get(versionCount).addSelectionListener(addSplitterCheckBoxListner(cbVersionSplitter));

            }
```

this my selection Adapter method

```
public SelectionAdapter addSplitterCheckBoxListner(final Button button){
        return new SelectionAdapter() {
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {


                String[] defaultVersionSplitters =  PropertyClass.getPropertyLabel(QTLConstants.VERSIONING_ASSISTENT_PAGE_SPLLITER).split(QTLConstants.MULTIPLE_EXTENSIONS_SPLITER);
                //check if button.getText() is equal to "Custom Splitter" String
                if(button.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(defaultVersionSplitters[3])){
                    if(button.getSelection()){
                        customVersionSplitterText.setEnabled(true);
                    }else{
                        customVersionSplitterText.setEnabled(false);
                    }

                }


            }

        };
    }
```

and OK cancel Buttons are added in this fashion

```
private void addOkCancelButtonOnVersionTreePopup(final Shell versionTreeComponentsShell){

        Button ok = componentsRenderer.createButtonWidget(versionTreeComponentsShell, SWT.PUSH,
                PropertyClass.getPropertyLabel(QTLConstants.OK_BUTTON));
        Button cancel = componentsRenderer.createButtonWidget(versionTreeComponentsShell, SWT.PUSH,
                PropertyClass.getPropertyLabel(QTLConstants.CANCEL_BUTTON));
        ok.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {

}
        });
}
cancel.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {          
                /*disposeSelectionListener(cbVersionSplitter);*/
                versionTreeComponentsShell.close();             
            }
        });

    }
}
```

so how can i remove this selection listener

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

1). Create class which will extend the `SelectionAdapter` class.

2). Override `widgetSelected()` method as you have done in your code.

3). Override `equals(Object other)` method with the following:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object other) {
   if (other == null) {
      return false;
   }
   if (other instanceof MyOwnSelectionAdapter) {
      return true;
   }
}
```

where `MyOwnSelectionAdapter` is your own implementation of `SelectionAdapter`.

4). Now you can do the following: `cancel.removeSelectionListener(new MyOwnSelectionAdapter());` and it will delete that selection listener.